# Bad HTTP Response code; Facebook likes don't post to facebook

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I've created post-specific like buttons on my wordpress website. They appear to work on my site and record likers etc, but nothing posts to facebook. I've tried several wordpress plugins. and all gave the same result. Twitter is working just fine. Upon debugging in the facebook open graph, I get "Bad Response Code URL returned a bad HTTP response code." (more info in the debug link below). What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

The posts can be viewed at http://www.nebulusentertainment.com/news.

You can check out my attempt at debugging here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nebulusentertainment.com%2Fjust-around-the-corner

Comment: Can you share your HTML code? It looks like you're missing a Meta Tag (at least according to the error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the page URL loading in the browser, they are loading with a status code of `500 - Internal Server Error`; which Facebook will reject.  Since you are using PHP, the fastest solution may be to  turn error reporting on, and display errors on.  Or take a look at your logs to see what's causing the 500 error.

You can see that your page quits outputting code are about `line 328`, which looks like it may be an error in the wordpress theme files somewhere (maybe `single.php`?).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It was indeed a php error, and now everything is working just fine. Thanks very much for your help cdbconcepts!

Answer (score 0):

The other reason would be, Facebook cannot access your webpage. probably because of your DNS entries or your server is behind a firewall for example your company LAN. Solution: Fix your DNS or Firewall blockages and make sure public social medias like Facebook has access to your sites.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but after I disabled my cache plugin "W3 Total Cache" everything worked fine .

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not about WordPress or, other CMS and website builder platform. Now a days in 2024, The issues is about authorization of your sites with facebook platform.

Facebook not only need OG header but also need Facebook Pages on header and check robots.txt whether you allow or not Facebook’s crawler user-agent: facebookexternalhit

I had summarize here after our customer encountered issues with Facebook URLs, resulting in a bad HTTP response code (403) when attempting to share links on the Facebook platform.

https://sobiztrend.com/facebook-url-returned-a-bad-http-response-code/